# R data frame to Excel but formulas show up as #DIV/0

Tags: r, excel, formulas

I have a data frame that comes from excel input and another excel spread sheet with a blank first page where I want the data to be imported to and a second sheet where there are formulas to calculate the average of the rows.

R Code:

```
require(xlsx)
require(XLConnect)
setwd("C:/Users/...")
## made up data that should becoming from an excel sheet
data <- matrix(c(3, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), nrow=3, ncol=4)
wb1 <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create=F)
as.numeric(data)
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb1, sheet = "Sheet2", T)
writeWorksheet( wb1,  data, sheet ="Sheet1" , startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header = F)
saveWorkbook(wb1, "Newtest.xlsx")
```

Excel Spreadsheet (test.xlsx - Sheet2):

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet1!A1:D1)
=AVERAGE(Sheet1!A2:D2)
=AVERAGE(Sheet1!A3:D3)
```

[Link to Image](http://s8.postimg.org/sdnvbafut/excelandr.png)

For the Image Link Above:

Left is the actual data, where the imported data from R has arrows on the top left (Indicating it is a text string) but once **I double click and hit enter the data is entered in correctly** which turns it into the actual number. I have tried using as.numeric, as.character but nothing changes the output of the data to numerical numbers.

On the right is a picture of the second excel spreadsheet with the formulas for the first code example which don't actually change the formulas.
(I actually cant upload the image because I dont have enough rep...)

This isn't the exact problem with my data, the formulas work if I go to each cell on the data and double click into the cell then hit enter. I think its the way the data was entered as both a character and numeric but I don't know which is messing it up. The actual code with the data is here:

```
require(xlsx)
require(XLConnect)
setwd("C:/Users/...")
wb <- loadWorkbook("ExcelTemplate.xlsx", create=F)
nws <- read.xlsx(file.choose(), sheetName="Results", header=FALSE, as.data.frame=TRUE, keepFormulas=TRUE)
## Adding rows to formate data to tempalte or wooksheet 2 of the workbook
r <- 39
newrow <- ""
nws = rbind(nws[1:39,],newrow,nws[-(1:39),], row.names=F)
rownames(nws) <- NULL
## Reduces data to only 9 columns 
wk2c <- nws[, c(1:9)]
names(wk2c) <- c("Well", "Well Position","Omit", "Sample Name", "Target Name", "Task", "Reporter", "Quencher", "CT")
## Changes all blanks to NA and all NA's to 0's
wk2c[, 9] <- as.numeric(as.character(wk2c[, 9]))
is.na(wk2c[, 9]) <- wk2c[, 9] <25
wk2c$CT[is.na(wk2c$CT)] <- 0
wk2c <- sapply(wk2c, as.character)
wk2c[is.na(wk2c)] <- ""
wk2c[1:39, 9] = ""
wk2c[40, 9] = "CT"
writeWorksheet( wb,  wk2c, sheet ="Paste Raw Data Here" , startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header = F)
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, sheet = "Paste Raw Data Here", T)
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, sheet = "Formatted Data", T)
setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, sheet = "Vertical Values", T)
saveWorkbook(wb, "NewdataPCR.xlsx")
```

So my question is how do I get data from one excel spreadsheet into R and export the data (with the correct format) from that excel spreadsheet into another (the formulas arent the problem the way the data is entered is!).

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem when the description is so vague and no Excel file is provided (i.e. it's not a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you edit and expand on the paragraph "Left is the actual data..." please? Also [you can upload that image within the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Sorry that it is difficult to understand, the problem I am having is that after importing my data into R and into the workbook. I export the workbook into excel, however **excel reads all the imported data as text** and **not numerical** so to fix this Ive tried different codes such as `write.xlsx`  `as.numeric` `as.character`  `setDataFormatForType(wb, type = XLC$"DATA_TYPE.NUMERIC", format = "0.00")`
`setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATA_FORMAT_ONLY")`

No matter what I do to the data it still comes out as strings of text and not numerical data. Thank you for all the help